# Understanding proof that no group of order $96$ is simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to understand the following proof that no group of order $96$ is simple:

> A group of order 96 has either 1 or 3 subgroups of order 32. If there
>   is only one such subgroup, it  is normal and we are done. If not, let
>   H and K be distinct subgroups of order 32. **By Lemma 37.8,  H ∩ K must
>    have order 16**, and is normal in both H and K, being of index 2. Thus
>    N[H ∩ K] has  order a multiple > 1 of 32 and a divisor of 96, so the
>   order must be 96. Thus H ∩ K is normal in the  whole group.

Lemma 37.8 talks about the formula $|H\cap K|  = \frac{|H||K|}{|HK|}$. But how does he find $|H\cap K| = 16$? It's assuming that it knows $|HK|$ to put in the formula, but how? How can he know $|HK|$?

Also: not a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/142839/166180 because I'm trying to understand a different proof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $|H\cap K|$ divides $32$ by Lagrange theorem as $H\cap K$ is a subgroup of $H$. If $|H\cap K |<16$ then $|HK|$ has more elements than $G$, which is impossible.

More clearly, $$|HK|=\dfrac{32*32}{|H\cap K|}\leq|G|=96$$
$$\dfrac{32}{3}\leq|H\cap K|$$

Thus, we must have $|H \cap K |=16$.

Comment: Thanks. One more thing... How does the order of the normalizer of $H\cap K$ being the entire group proves that $H\cap K$ ir normal in $G$?

Comment: $N_G(H\cap K)\geq H,K$. Thus, $|N_G(H\cap K)|\geq |HK|=64$. Can you conclude now ?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs: Apparently, you did not conclude ?

Comment: Why is $ H,K \le N_G(H \cap K)$ ?

Comment: @Hristmar: As $|H:H\cap K|=2$, $H\cap K \lhd H$. Similarly, $H\cap K \lhd K$.